# showing an element by clicking button and hiding by clicking anywhere else

Tags: jquery, global-variables, visibility

I need to set a global click action only if , let's say, `<div id="hidden"></div>` is visible.

Setting the global function is simple :

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    $("#hidden").fadeOut(700);
});
```

But I also have:

```
$("#hidden").hide();
$("#button").click(function(e) {
    $("#hidden").fadeIn(700);
});
```

And these two don't work together cause on first click it would `fadeIn` and also `fadeOut` the `#hidden`

I tried using :

```
$("#button").click(function(){
        $("#hidden").fadeIn(500);
    });

    if($("#hidden").is(":visible")) {
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        $("#hidden").fadeOut(700);
    });
} 
else {
}
```

...but no use...

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/VMAJ7/20/)

Comment: It isn't yet clear what you want your logic to do.  If I were to guess, you have a button which when clicked shows something and if clicked again hides something ... but that isn't coming across in the question properly.  Would you be able to enhance the question?

Comment: @Kolban What I need is when the button is clicked, an object to fadein, and not when clicked again but when anything else on the page is clicked, the object to fadeOut. that's why I set the global variable for click.

Comment: @Kolban I will put together a jsfiddle to make things easier, ok ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target) in the global function:

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if (e.target.id == "button") $("#hidden").fadeIn(500);
  else $("#hidden").fadeOut(700);
});
```

```css
#hidden {
  display: none;
  height: 50px;
  background: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hidden"></div>
<button id="button">Show</button>
```

Comment: It doesn't work...What I need is when the button is clicked, an object to fadein, and not when clicked again but when anything else on the page is clicked, the object to fadeOut. that's why I set the global variable for click.

Comment: @Alin http://jsfiddle.net/VMAJ7/21/ . Use CSS for presentation purpose, add `display:none` instead of using jquery to hide an element on page load. Also, you can use the inbuilt [stack snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/2333214) for providing runnable demos :)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the stack snippet function yet but it's great :) also, it's working nicely :) I wanted to ask something more, can I target the data-rel ? As in e.target.id  but for data-rel ?

Comment: @Alin try `$(e.target).data("rel")` or `$(e.target).attr("data-rel")`

Comment: Works great :)) why can't I give you more +1's ?! :)) Have a great day, thanks once again.